# How to get class attributes by using a custom object's accessors when the object is selected in a JComboBox?

Tags: arraylist, jcombobox

I need help with using JComboBox: I have an ArrayList which I load into my JComboBox.

Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class JFrameOrder extends JFrame {
    ArrayList <Customer> cust = new ArrayList<Customer>();

public JFrameOrder() {
    initComponents();
    Inventory.createCustomers();
    cust = Inventory.customerList();
    jCboCustName.addItem("");
    for (Customer c : cust){
        jCboCustName.addItem(c);
    }
```

The Inventory class has a method which creates the ArrayList - customer list.
The Customer class has two fields: int custID and String custName.
It also has accessors and mutators. 
I can get the JComboBox to show the name by Overriding  ToString. 
I want to update a JLabel to show the corresponding custID based on the selection.

If the jCboCustName.getSelectedItem() returns an object, shouldn't I be able to use the object's accessors and mutators? After all I did load the element in as an Object. Please help.

Thanks in advance.